# PHP / SQL display dates in format

Tags: php, sql, date

In an SQL database I'm storing various dates, such as date of birth and date they joined my system, in the standard SQL format `YYYY-mm-dd`, however I wish to display these to my British users (all my users) in the format `dd-mm-YYYY`.

I've tried pretty much everything I found online about doing this, however cannot decipher how it's done correctly. The code I list below is what I am currently using, however it does not display the correct date stored in the database and instead uses a completely random date of `01-01-1970`. Some assistance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
                array_push($_SESSION["ActQueue"], array($row["username"], $row["surname"], $row["forename"], date('d-m-Y', $row["dob"]), $row["gender"], $row["joined"]));
}

$data = 0;
echo json_encode(['Username'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][0], 'Surname'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][1],'Forename'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][2],'DoB'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][3], 'Gender'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][4], 'Joined'=>$_SESSION["ActQueue"][0][5]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your plain text date to time before passing to `date()` function

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row["dob"]))
```

The date you receive `01-01-1970` its not a random date but its actually the first date from unix system

Comment: This has the intended effect, but adds an extra "-", like this: `Date of Birth: 30-11--0001`. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean? You can add whatever you need in date function like two minus symbols

Comment: It changes the date to `dd-mm-YYYY` format, but adds an extra "-" for some reason, like `30-11--0001`.

Comment: How does it look `row['dob']` if you print before pass to date function?

Comment: `strtotime($row["dob"])` outputs `-62169984000`. $row["dob"] outputs `0000-00-00`

Comment: So the problem is with the string you are passing to the function, are you sure the column is called `dob` in your mysql table? The error is somewhere else

Comment: Yeh, the collum is there and is in the date format. Calling $row['dob] works normally just in the wrong format.

Comment: As you said `$row["dob"] outputs 0000-00-00` you need to understand why, it should print the date correctly as you see in your db, when it will the date function will work as expected

Comment: Ah whoops. I just remembered that the date function does not work with empty dates (`0000-00-00`), so testing it on one of those dates caused the odd behavior. I've changed the account I was testing it on and it now seems to work fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use :

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row["dob"]))
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this this code to format your date

```
(new \DateTime($row["dob"]))->format('d-m-Y');
```